# SQL CE 4.0 in Reference Manager of VS

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

There

I install both of SQL CE version 3.5 and 4.0 on my development machine, which installed VS 2012.
My problem is: But I cannot find 4.0 version from "Reference Manager" of VS. Please look at the screen shots as below.

**First:** You can see both of them from "programs and features", and the installation sequence is: x86-3.5 --> x64-3.5 --> x64-4.0. And I restarted computer after each installation.
[image]

**Second:** But I cannot find System.Data.SqlServerCe 4.0.0.0 version from "Reference Manager" of VS.
[image]

**Third:** This is my another machine which has the same environment, but 4.0 could be found.
[image]
I also compare their registry value regarding of SQL CE section, all are the same.

Appreciate if anyone could provide help on this.

Answer (score 1):

In order to add a reference to SQL CE 4.0, just browse to the 4.0 DLL, which is located in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v4.0\Desktop
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is solution, but the 4.0 reference is add by "Assemblies-->Extensions " but not "Browse" in "Reference Manager". If I did in that way, other developer will confused on that why I did that. We are team project, maintenance by lots of developer. I think this is my machine's environment issue, I need find the root reason.